# Aplicar opacity apenas em background

Tags: css

Tenho uma div e texto escrito dentro dela.

```
.topoMenuSegmentos {
width: 470px;
height: 190px;
background-color: #0a1737;
display: block;
margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Quero aplicar um `opacity:0.8`, o que acontece é que o texto que está dentro dessa div também fica com a opacidade.

Existe alguma alternativa?

Comment: http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html utiliza isso, resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Se você usar na cor do background o formato RGBa isso deve funcionar.

Teste assim:

```
background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.5);
```

Onde `0.5` é o nível de opacidade.

Para browsers antigos (IE9-) a solução é outra. Aí pode usar 2 divs, não descendentes uma da outra e posicionálas uma em cima da outra.

Alternativa é usar um `.png` semi-transparente como imagem de fundo usando background-repeat no caso de o tamanho da div ser adaptativo.

Comment: Sérgio, o `opacity` é incompatível com o IE8?

Comment: @FelipeStoker o IE8 já não é suportado pela Microsoft por isso eu também deixei de suportar :P Agora a sério: a resposta é não. Para fazer isso no IE8 tem de ter uma div sobreposta a outra, sem uma ser descendente da outra.

Comment: Eu também não suporto o IE ahah, mas sabe como é, muitos usuários ainda usam-o. É, estava lendo e para o IE8, o ideal é um .png transparente. :D

Comment: :) @FelipeStoker juntei info para IE9- na resposta também.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar colocar uma `div` dentro de outra. Como no exemplo abaixo:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   position: relative;
}

.container .bg {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; 
   left: 0;
   background: #000;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Estava com esse mesmo problema e achei uma solução!!

HTML:

```
<div class="opacity">
      <h1>Colocando Opacidade apenas no Background</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.opacity {
    background-image: url(img/pc.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.opacity::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: -1;
```